Match a Regex Pattern that doesn't follow the serial arrangement in the pattern
How do i match a string to a regex pattern in javascript, but the string does not have to follow the serial arrangement in the regex Pattern.
The regex pattern test against a string containing brackets with the conditions that;

Open brackets must be closed by the same type of brackets.
Open brackets must be closed in the correct order.
Every close bracket has a corresponding open bracket of the same type.

This is what i tried;
const pattern = /^(\(\))*(\{\})*(\[\])*$/

if i test it against these strings, it works fine
console.log(pattern.test("(){}[]")) //returns true
console.log(pattern.test("(]") //returns false

but if change the order the brackets appear in the regex then i get false
console.log(pattern.test("{}()[]") // returns false

I want the string of brackets to match the pattern no matter which brackets comes first or second as long as they meet the above conditions

This is not a problem particularly well suited to solve with a regex.

Open brackets must be closed in the correct order. ... in the general case, you need a parser, not just a regex pattern.

Sounds like ^(?:\(\)|\[]|{})*$

Did anything work for you?

If your task is to match any string that consists of one or more occurrences of a pair of empty brackets/parentheses/braces, you can simply use a regex solution like
^(?:\(\)|\[]|{})+$

See the regex demo.
Details

^ - start of string
(?:\(\)|\[]|{})+ - one or more occurrences of

\(\) - a () substring
| - or
\[] - a [] substring
| - or
{} - a {} substring


$ - end of string.

